# Advantage of Custom UI buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I have been interviewing for an iOS job and have been getting a lot of questions about custom UI, and more specifically custom UI buttons. I started trying to read up about it and found that Core Graphics is used to make these custom buttons.

I was wondering what the advantage of using custom buttons made with corE graphics is over using a UIImage, and images created on adobe or sketch, and then putting a UI button over that. Is there any specific advantage other then more customization over the process?

As an aside I was wondering if there were any good core graphics (Quartz 2d) tutorials out there for obj-c, I have found a good amount with swift, but not so many with obj-c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's interesting that it's an interview question!

You can design buttons in [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/) which converts your drawings into code.  Supposedly with Core Graphics, the performance is better, and it should look good regardless of the size of the device.  PaintCode says about the Benefits: "Resolution independence & other benefits No more @2x resources. Future proof. Creating dynamic, parametric drawings is easy."

For the details, I would check out the [FAQ, Question 2](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/faq). Here are the first few paragraphs:

> Using PNG images to draw user interfaces is tedious. PNG images are
>   not resolution-independent, so you have to provide many variants for
>   all kinds of displays. Some effects are also difficult (if not
>   impossible) to achieve using raster images. For exampe, you might want
>   to draw something with complex resizing behavior, or you might want to
>   alter the color of the drawing based on some outer conditions.
>
> A better approach than using images is to use Objective-C or Swift
>   code to draw the user interface. The code is resolution-independent
>   and very flexible, so it works really well on all kinds of displays.

On a side note though, I find that it is a lot easier to use images rather than PaintCode.  The positioning of elements, taking into consideration the insets in the image itself vs the inset in code causes a bunch of problems in practice. And PaintCode uses springs and struts as well to help with the sizing of images on different devices, but you have to be careful with when combining that with layout constraints in storyboard.  There are things you can do in PaintCode to make your life a bit, but it takes some practice to really get the hang of it.  Making the @2x and @3x versions of images is really not that bad - so if you can avoid PaintCode, I would just to avoid the headache.

Comment: Thanks a lot, if i could up vote this would def get one.

Comment: You can accept it as the answer though without an up vote.